# Does toggling the WLAN button on a Huawei HG659 router survive a reboot?

Tags: wireless-router

Does toggling the WLAN button on a Huawei HG659 router survive a reboot?

For example, if I instructed someone on how to permanently disable their WLAN connection will this do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does toggling the WLAN button on the HG659 survive a reboot?

If you disable WLAN the only way it would be enabled again is if somebody enabled it or they reset the device.  A simple reboot of the device would not enable WLAN if it was disabled.